# RefrenceError: Can't find variable in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-video

I tried to access all the files in a custom folder I created on my RNCamera roll app to create a gallery with it. In my code I believe i specified the variable "videos", but still am getting a reference error: "can't find variable videos", what do i do to solve it, how will i be able to get rid of the error.... here is my code...

I added constructor in the this.state but still get the same error

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        videos: [],
        index: null
    }
  }


    getPhotos = () => {
        CameraRoll.getPhotos({
            first: 20,
            groupTypes: 'Album',
            groupName: 'Custom VideoFolder',
            assetType: 'Videos'
        })
        .then(r => this.setState({ videos: r.edges}))
        .then((statResult) => {
        let videos = []
        var allowedExtensions = /(\.avi|\.mp4|\.mov|\.wmv|\.avi)$/i;
        statResult.forEach(item => {
        if (item.isFile() && !allowedExtensions.exec(item.originalFilepath)) {
        videos.push(item)
        }
        });
        console.log(videos)
        })
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
      this.setState({ modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible})
  }


  share = () => {
    const vocvideo = this.state.videos[this.state.index].node.video.uri
    RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(vocvideo, 'uri')
    .then((data) => {
      let shareOptions = {
        title: "React Native Share Example",
        message: "Check out this video!",
        url: `data:video/mp4;uri,${data}`,
        subject: "Check out this video!"
      };

      Share.open(shareOptions)
        .then((res) => console.log('res:', res))
        .catch(err => console.log('err', err))
    })
  }

      render() {
        console.log('state :', this.state)
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
              title='View videos'
              onPress={() => { this.toggleModal(); this.getPhotos() }}
            />
            <Modal
              animationType={"slide"}
              transparent={false}
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}
            >
              <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                <Button
                  title='Close'
                  onPress={this.toggleModal}
                />
                <ScrollView
                  contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
                  {
                    this.state.videos.map((p, i) => {
                      const isSelected = i === this.state.index;
                      const divide = isSelected && this.share === true ? 1 : 3;
                      return (
                        <Video
                          style={{opacity: i === this.state.index ? 0.5 : 1, width: width/divide, height: width/divide}}
                          key={i}
                          underlayColor='transparent'
                          onPress={() => this.setIndex(i)}
                          source={{uri: video}}
                        />
                        
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Which line of code is producing the issue? Also you added a code snippet, which should be able to run. But you meant to add code just to read (I think since there is nothing after ScrollView).  I recommend changing it from a snippet to code (spaced at least 4 times).

Comment: this.state.videos.map((p, i) => {
This is the code giving the error

Comment: Can you try declaring `this.state` in the constructor instead?

Comment: Still got the same error after using this.state in the constructor. How can I solve this error please.